# localize_script but data changes dependent on product ID

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, wp-enqueue-script, wp-localize-script

I currently have this code in my `functions.php` file.

```
$dataToBePassed = array();
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
        $handle  = 'three-d-scripts';
        $src     = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/src/scripts/three-d-scripts.js';
        $deps    = [];
        $version = '1.0.0';
        wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $version, true );
} );
wp_localize_script( 'three-d-scripts', 'php_vars', $dataToBePassed );
```

What I am wanting to do is change the contents of `dataToBePassed` dependent on the product ID of the currently view products is this possible?

I have tried,

`global $product;   $product->get_id();`

but this returns NULL as does,

`global $post;   $post->ID;`

What I was hoping to achieve is something this,

```
global $product;
$product_id = $product->get_id();
$dataToBePassed = array();
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
        $handle  = 'three-d-scripts';
        $src     = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/src/scripts/three-d-scripts.js';
        $deps    = [];
        $version = '1.0.0';
        wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $version, true );
} );
switch($product_id) {
    case 1:
        //do something
    break;
    case 2:
        //do something
    break;
    default:
       //do something
    break;

}
wp_localize_script( 'three-d-scripts', 'php_vars', $dataToBePassed );
```

Any ideas how I can get the woocommerce product ID so I can switch over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) in the [`wp_enqueue_scripts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) (or a later hook) in which you would get the correct product/post data such as ID, and that conditional tags like [`is_single()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) would also work as expected.

So you should move all the `$product`, `$product_id`, `$dataToBePassed` and `wp_localize_script()` parts to *inside the `wp_enqueue_scripts` callback*, and then you'd get the correct product/post ID, etc. See an example below, and note that:

- `is_product()` and `wc_get_product()` are WooCommerce functions, and I used the former because I presumed your script should only be loaded on single product pages? (like one at `example.com/product/product-foo/`)
- Also, just like one should do `$post = get_post()`, you should also do `$product = wc_get_product()` to properly get the current product/post object/data.

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_three_d_scripts' );
function my_theme_enqueue_three_d_scripts() {
    if ( ! is_product() ) {
        return;
    }

    $handle  = 'three-d-scripts';
    $src     = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/src/scripts/three-d-scripts.js';
    $deps    = array();
    $version = '1.0.0';
    wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $version, true );

    $product        = wc_get_product();
    $product_id     = $product ? $product->get_id() : 0;
    $dataToBePassed = array();

    switch ( $product_id ) {
        case 1:
            $dataToBePassed = array( 'product_id' => 1 );
            break;

        case 2:
            $dataToBePassed = array( 'product_id' => 2 );
            break;

        default:
            $dataToBePassed = array( 'product_id' => 0 );
            break;
    }

    // PS: Instead of php_vars, use a unique name like my_three_d_vars..
    wp_localize_script( $handle, 'php_vars', $dataToBePassed );
}
```